# Como hacer lograr que una imagen se vea completo al momento de poner el cel en modo horizontal

Tags: java, android-imageview

Tengo un detalle con una imagen cuando tengo el celular en posición horizontal no se ve completa como que se oculta una parte detrás del `toolbar`, y en modo normal si se ve completa.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="FragmentEvacuacion.Proceso_evacuacion"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

**Posición vertical**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Posición Horizontal**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La imagen no se muestra completa ya que usas `centerCrop`. Antes de tomar una decisión sobre que propiedad usar para mostrar tu imagen, debes tomar en cuenta que el aspecto de la imagen en la mayoría de las ocasiones no coincidirá con el aspecto del contenedor.

Si deseas que se muestre completamente dentro del contenedor manteniendo la relación de aspecto de la imagen de modo que ambas dimensiones (ancho y alto) de la imagen sean iguales o menores que la dimensión correspondiente de la vista (menos relleno) puedes usar:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Si deseas mostrar la imagen a partir de las coordenadas X y Y del contenedor, puedes usar:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY".
```

Al usar `centerInside`, `fitCenter`, `fitEnd` y `fitStart`, los límites reales de `ImageView` son mucho más grandes que la imagen escalada. Para establecer los límites de `ImageView` a la altura de la imagen en el interior, usa:

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes revisar más información sobre todas las propiedades en :

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

https://abhiandroid.com/ui/scaletype-imageview-example.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys me sirvió la información

Comment: Excelente @Miguel , saludos!